# return values from Jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a complete novice in jQuery and javascript, so if this sounds very silly or very simple thing to do please help me out with your expertise

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#add_button').click(function(){
    var vol = $('input#cv').val();
    var col = $('input#cc').val();
    var comment = $('input#co').val();
    var sample = $('#cv').attr('class');
    var url = $('input#cv').attr('title');
    if( (vol && col && comment)  == ''){
      alert('No data to update');
    }else{
      url =  url.concat('volupdate=',vol,'&concupdate=',col,'&commupdate=',comment,'&sample=',sample);

      alert(sample + " " + vol + " " + col +" "+ comment +" " + url);
    }
  });
});
```

html :

```
my $correct_vol = qq{<input type="text" name="cv" id="cv" size="6" class="$sample_name" title="/here/is/where/you/are">};
my $correct_conc = qq{<input type="text" name="cc" id="cc" size="6" class="$sample_name" title="/here/is/where/you/are">};
my $comments = qq{<input type="text" name="co" id="co" size="10" class="$sample_name" title="/here/is/where/you/are">};
my $update = q{<input type="submit" value="Update" id="add_button" class="add_now">};
```

These forms the last four columns in a big table. 
My question is:  How should I return the url in jquery function to my perl?

if I use `return url` what should I expect ? And how should I handle the values passed from the `url` in my script? Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript code won't connect with your perl code by itself. The connections to perl will happen as it processes the form elements. So your values need to be passed via POST or GET, the same way they would be passed if you were doing this in an HTML + perl only solution.

What you can do in your javascript is to set the value of the form input that you need to pass. That would be accomplished via something like `$("#inputElementID").val(url);` (assuming that you give the input element an id of `inputElementID` in the html where you create it.

You could also submit the form through javascript, if it made sense to do so.

As to using `return url`, that will only end up returning the value of `url` to the javascript function that calls it (which, in this case, doesn't really exist since this is a `document.ready()` execution.